# Generating a failure based on the exponential distribution

Tags: r, random, probability, sample

I need to generate data for failures according to the behavior of 3 other parameters (A, B, and C). For example: If A > 10, B > 10, and C > 10, the probability of a failure is 0.99. Otherwise, if A < 10, B > 10, and C > 10, the probability is 0.30. How to generate these failures knowing that they follow an exponential distribution?

I want to generate data for 100 periods, i.e., for each period I want to have information on whether or not there is a failure.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: your question leaves various states undefined, e.g. what about `A > 10 & B > 10 & C < 10`?  also where does the exponential distribution come from?  @Jakob puts a functional call in there to reference the exponential distribution, but these are just equivalent to using bernoulli trials with a given probability of success (e.g. `rexp(n, rate=0.99)` is just a probability of success of ~0.63) and would likely be better explained and coded as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to specify what happens in the other cases, but you want to use the `rexp()` function and then either write a function or use if else statements along the lines of:

```
if (A>10 & B>10 & C>10) {
  rexp(100, rate=0.99)
} else {
  rexp(100, rate=0.30)
}
```

**Update:**
Sounds like you want something like this:

```
if (A>10 & B>10 & C>10) {
  p = rpois(100, rate=0.99)
} else {
  p = rpois(100, rate=0.30)
}
p[p>0]=1
```

The if-else creates a vector `p` with the number of estimated failures per period. The last line then codes all periods with any failure as a `1` and `0` otherwise.

Comment: The function rexp will generate continuous values. However, I need to specify if there is a failure (1) or not (0) in the period.

Comment: Do you want to know the number of failures per period or just if there has been any failure? For the former, just replace `rexp` above with `rpois`. Otherwise do something like `p = rpois(100, 0.99); p[p>0]=1`

Comment: Just if there has been any failure.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Try running these one by one and looking at the output after each: `p = rpois(100, 0.99)` will draw 100 random variables from a Poission distribution with lambda=0.99. This will create a vector `p` with a 100 entries, each telling you the number of failures in that time period. Then `p[p>0]=1` selects those values of this vector that are greater than zero and assigns them a 1. So say there were 2 failures in one period, this will be coded as a 1.